# Problem with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, html, apache

I have a simple problem with the server global variable named : DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Here's my config.php file :

```
<?php
define ('UPLOAD_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resouces/');
```

The test.php file

```
<?php

$photo='myimage.php';
echo '<img src="'.UPLOAD_DIR.$photo.'">';
```

The problem is that when testing the code.. The image doesn't display, and the directory starts with :

> C://program files/easyPHP/www/resources

instead of

> http://127.0.0.1:8888/

As it supposed to be... I tried to update this line in the httpd.conf file :

```
DocumentRoot "${path}/www"
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "http://127.0.0.1:8888/www"
```

But the server declares an error :

[image]

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do...  Also, don't allow uploads directly to anything under the document root.  You are opening yourself to world a security troubles if you do this.

Comment: Thank you brad ... I will really avoid'em +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is path on your real filesystem.
You need not it here. 
Just use

```
define ('UPLOAD_DIR','/resouces/');
```

Don't mix up path on filesystem and path on your site.
They may have nothing common (but in default case requested `URI` sent to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].URI`)

You can also use

```
define ('UPLOAD_DIR_FILEPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resouces/'); //to use in upload, renaming, deleting etc
define ('UPLOAD_DIR_WWW','/resouces/'); //to show URLs
```

You need not declare it on every levelb ecause path starts from root `/`

Comment: The problem Riad is that I use this resources file in many directories with different levels ... so do I have to declare a constant for every level???

Comment: @Simo TAQI, you need not constant to every level, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you, but Brad said me that using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in uploads my have some troubles on security. 

But you're solution is still working +1

Comment: Thank you friends ... it's now working , I removed the Document_root from the code that shows URLs

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding `DOCUMENT_ROOT`; it's the path to the root directory that code is served from, not an IP, which is why you're getting the error in the screenshot. Also, when you're uploading files, you actually *want* the file path, not the server IP.

From the docs:

> [Document root is] The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

When you put paths to files in HTML, it's very *very* bad practice to use the server's IP; it should be a file path. It's much better to use a relative file path instead of an absolute one; it reveals much less about your site to the public, making it a bit more secure.

Comment: But what's the solution then?? and why my images are not displaying?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or you can work with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.  See:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php  Those will help you get the currently running script.  If you want the doc root, just use `/`.  That's where the doc root will be on the web side of things.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing between Physical Path and WWW URL.

Comment: I really know the difference between them, my images are displaying the C:// path, and I want the 127.0.0.1 path ,or localhost :-)

Comment: In a previous version of apache , I was using the DOCUMENT_ROOT variable for the WWW URL , not the physical path... this is the first time I had this error

Comment: Just use `echo '<img src="/resource/'.$photo.'">';`

Comment: I have one config.php file... and many directories with different levels ... I have to use this config.php file to point to the same directory (uploads) from all those directories.. so , if I host the project , I will change the resources directory from one file :-)